# StackOverflowError with tuple

Tags: julia

I have written a recursive function for getting objects in larger arrays in julia. The following error occured:

```
ERROR: LoadError: StackOverflowError:
     in cat_t at abstractarray.jl:831
     in recGetObjChar at /home/user/Desktop/program.jl:1046
     in recGetObjChar at /home/user/Desktop/program.jl:1075 (repeats 9179 times)
     in getImChars at /home/user/Desktop/program.jl:968
     in main at /home/user/Desktop/program.jl:69
     in include at ./boot.jl:261
     in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:304
     in process_options at ./client.jl:308
     in _start at ./client.jl:411
    while loading /home/user/Desktop/program.jl, in expression starting on line 78
```

If you want to have a look at the code, I have already opened an issue ([Assertion failed, process aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461722/assertion-failed-process-aborted)). After debugging my code for julia v 0.4, it is more obvious, what causes the problem. The tupel locObj gets much bigger than 9000 entries, because one object can be e.g. 150 x 150 big. 
That would result in a length of 22500 for locObj. How big can tupels get, and how can I avoid a stackoverflow? Is there another way to save my values?

Comment: IMO, using machine RAM as an inventory for big array of data, may lead you to different kinds of memory related issues, so it's better to store them in file, Julia provides different ways to work with data files: https://github.com/svaksha/Julia.jl/blob/master/Database.md, but my suggestion for the kind of your data, is to store them in a **Memory-mapped** array, Memory-mapped is a julia built-in tool that helps you working on big array of data, http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/io-network/#memory-mapped-i-o

Comment: @LuWi Apologies. I actually didn't even bother following the link, so I didn't know it led to a SO question. I'll delete my earlier comment.

Answer (score 3):

As it's commented, I think better approaches exist to work with big arrays of data, and this answer is mainly belongs to this part of your question:

> Is there another way to save my values?

I have prepared a test to show how using `mmap` is helpful when dealing with big array of data, following functions both do the same thing: they create a vector of 3*10E6 `float64`, then fill it, calculate `sum` and print result, in the first one (`mmaptest()`), a memory-map structure have been used to store `Vector{Float64}` while second one (`ramtest()`) do the work on machine ram:

```
function mmaptest()
  s = open("./tmp/mmap.bin","w+") # tmp folder must exists in pwd() path
  A = Mmap.mmap(s, Vector{Float64}, 3_000_000)
  for j=1:3_000_000
    A[j]=j
  end
  println("sum = $(sum(A))")
  close(s)
end

function ramtest()
  A = Vector{Float64}(3_000_000)
  for j=1:3_000_000
    A[j]=j
  end
  println("sum = $(sum(A))")
end
```

then both functions have been called and memory allocation size was calculated:

```
julia> gc(); # => remove old handles to closed stream

julia> @allocated mmaptest()
  sum = 4.5000015e12
  861684

julia> @allocated ramtest()
  sum = 4.5000015e12
  24072791
```

It's obvious from those tests that with a memory-map object, memory allocation is much smaller.

```
julia> gc()

julia> @time ramtest()
  sum = 4.5000015e12
  0.012584 seconds (29 allocations: 22.889 MB, 3.43% gc time)

julia> @time mmaptest()
  sum = 4.5000015e12
  0.019602 seconds (58 allocations: 2.277 KB)
```

as it's clear from @time test, using `mmap` makes the code slower while needs less memory.

I wish it helps you, regards.

Comment: Dear Reza Afzalan, thanks a lot for your nice answer. This was very helpful and i will use it for my further programming in julia! I have rewritten my code to get the root of the problem and the whole algorithm works much better with a working example. If you want to have look at the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660916/vcat-stackoverflowerror-in-julia. Thanks a lot, regards clax