# Reading hex string file in Julia

Tags: binary, julia, memory-mapped-files, hexdump

In python, I do

```
import numpy as np
data = np.memmap('mydata.bin', dtype='<i4', mode='r')
```

How can I implement this in Julia? I was reading about `readbytes` and `htol` but couldn't figure out.

Comment: Here I have written a small sample that could helps you with Julia memory-mapped functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487832/stackoverflowerror-with-tuple

Comment: are you looking for [`mmap`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=mmap#Base.Mmap.mmap)?

Comment: I didn't find any option that helps setting endian format when reading/writing mmap data, but if on your host machine `ENDIAN_BOM==0x04030201 # => false`, so it's a big endiran, then one possibility might be convert data with `ltoh()` function. (I'm not sure about whole thing)

Comment: @RezaAfzalan Thanks. I think it came out with the right format. Later I did the bitwise operation `Mmap.mmap(f,Vector{Int32}) & 0x7ffffff` . It looks same as python code.